# sidekiq - uninitialized constant RegistrationsWorker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

I use Sidekiq and this below is my code:

authentications_controller.rb:

```
def auth_provider auth, user
 ....
 ....
 Facebook.loop_import fb_user, 'POST', user
end
```

Facebook.rb:

```
def self.loop_import(fb_user, type, user)
 fb_user.posts({:locale => user.language}).each do |post|
    p = Post.where(:id_ref_facebook => post.raw_attributes['id'].to_s).first
    if p.blank?
      #self.import post, user
      RegistrationsWorker.perform_async(post.raw_attributes['id'])
    else
      self.update post, user, p
    end
 end if type == 'POST'
end
```

app/workers/registrations_worker.rb:

```
class RegistrationsWorker
 include Sidekiq::Worker

 def perform p_id

  Rails.logger.info '--------------------------------------------------'
  Rails.logger.info p_id
  Rails.logger.info '--------------------------------------------------'

 end
end
```

I have this result when try registration in the sidekiq terminal:

```
2014-08-06T16:18:25.541Z 14818 TID-ige3o WARN: {"retry"=>true, "queue"=>"default", "class"=>"RegistrationsWorker", "args"=>["1587189554_10203486498754922"], "jid"=>"3299251e473686b00b027b7b", "enqueued_at"=>1407341905.534449}
2014-08-06T16:18:25.542Z 14818 TID-ige3o WARN: uninitialized constant RegistrationsWorker
2014-08-06T16:18:25.542Z 14818 TID-ige3o WARN: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:238:in `const_get'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:238:in `block in constantize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:236:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:236:in `inject'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:236:in `constantize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/activesupport-4.1.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:66:in `constantize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/sidekiq-3.2.1/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:46:in `process'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/celluloid-0.15.2/lib/celluloid/calls.rb:25:in `public_send'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/celluloid-0.15.2/lib/celluloid/calls.rb:25:in `dispatch'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/celluloid-0.15.2/lib/celluloid/calls.rb:122:in `dispatch'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/celluloid-0.15.2/lib/celluloid/actor.rb:322:in `block in handle_message'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/celluloid-0.15.2/lib/celluloid/actor.rb:416:in `block in task'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/celluloid-0.15.2/lib/celluloid/tasks.rb:55:in `block in initialize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/celluloid-0.15.2/lib/celluloid/tasks/task_fiber.rb:13:in `block in create'
2014-08-06T16:18:25.547Z 14818 TID-11ila4 WARN: {"retry"=>true, "queue"=>"default", "class"=>"RegistrationsWorker", "args"=>["1587189554_10203485726855625"], "jid"=>"33eec574e1dad7f27eb78862", "enqueued_at"=>1407341905.5392146}
2014-08-06T16:18:25.550Z 14818 TID-11ila4 WARN: uninitialized constant RegistrationsWorker
```

Comment: Have you restarted Sidekiq since you created that worker class?

Comment: bundle exec sidekiq ??

Comment: Probably?  if that's what you're using to run it...  It tends not to pick up now class definitions without a restart.

Comment: Can you access `RegistrationsWorker` fom `rails console`?

Comment: you may need a `-r` flag. ex. `bundle exec sidekiq -r app/workers/registrations_worker.rb`

Comment: Since you resolved, can you please write the answer with the solution and mark it, or instead delete the question?

Answer (score 2):

Restart sidekiq after each new modification.

Answer (score -2):

ok i restart sidekiq and the queue is ok;

now i change this code :

```
class RegistrationsWorker
 include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform p_id

   Rails.logger.info '--------------------------------------------------'
   Rails.logger.info p_id
   Rails.logger.info '--------------------------------------------------'

 end
end
```

in:

```
class RegistrationsWorker
 include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform p_id

   @post = Post.new();
   @post.save(:validate => false)

 end
end
```

but nor write in mongoDB databases;

the message in console is all start and done;

Comment: Except the part that restarting sidekiq has done the trick for the uninitalized constant this isn't really an answer. Please consider to update your original question with your new problem or create a new question. In both cases you should remove the "new question part" from this answer.

Comment: using parenthesis after `new`? semi-colon WHY? `p_id` it's not being used.. huge code smell preventing to run validations